# What does _. mean in patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Here is a quick one, hopefully. I searched through different tutorials and documentation articles but haven't been able to find anything yet.

What does `_.` mean? As in `{_,_.}` as opposed to `{_,_}` or `{_,_,_.}` as opposed to `{_,_,_}`?

Thanks!

Comment: "I searched through different tutorials and documentation articles but haven't been able to find anything yet." Then you haven't yet learned the correct usage of document: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVvvv.gif

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! I didn't actually know about that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) will show you how an expression is really interpreted,

```
In[5]:= FullForm[_.]

Out[5]= Optional[Blank[]]
```

This tells you you need to look at [`Optional`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html) and [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) to understand this particular syntax.

This is especially important for infix operators like this, because for some the <kbd>F1</kbd> documentation search doesn't bring up a relevant page.  Take the expression

```
x // f
```

or

```
f @ x
```

Running `FullForm` on either of these returns `f[x]` - telling you immediately what the notation means. This is good because if you highlight the `@` or `//` and hit <kbd>F1</kbd> you will find [`Prefix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prefix.html) and [`Postfix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html), which aren't very helpful for understanding what those symbols mean. But `FullForm` will tell you how your syntax is interpreted by the front end, and what it is sent to the kernel as.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning some of the basics, I should have thought to use FullForm[] :)

Comment: @Jmeeks29ig - glad to help!

Comment: I messed up when first commenting on this, so I cannot claim that the answer is trivial (and I wish the question hadn't been closed). It would be useful to include a few examples about how `Optional[]` is used. So far we learnt that `_.` is one shorthand for `Optional`. The more common shorthand is `:`, e.g. `x_ : defaultValue`. With this pattern, the name `x` will be assigned the explicitly written `defaultValue`.  With `f[x_.]`, the value of `x` will be taken from `Default[f]`. Here it is necessary to have the enclosing symbol `f`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this fully answers the question I posted, but after some more searching, I have discovered that it seems like `_.` evaluates to `Optional[]`, at least when using `ReplaceAll[]`. An example will be better than words:

```
{_, _.} /. _Blank -> g
```

evaluates to:

```
{g, Optional[g]}
```

I know this is not a full answer, but hopefully it is at least partially helpful.